# Can we use multiple mutlicast in apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis, multicast

I have a requirement where i want to use mutlicast in Apache Camel for than single time in a single route. i.e Multicast within a multicast.

```
    <routeContext id="myRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="myRouteId">
            <from uri="activemq:queue:{{XXXX.queue}}" />
      .... 
            <multicast parallelProcessing="true">
                <pipeline>
                    ##everything working fine here
                </pipeline>
                <pipeline>
                    <multicast>
                        <pipeline>
                            <log message="Inserting in database now"></log>
                            <transform>
                                <method ref="insertBean" method="myBatchInsertion"></method>
                            </transform>
                              <choice>
                                <when>
                                    <simple>${in.header.myCount} == ${properties:batch.size} </simple>
                                    <to uri="sql:{{sql.core.insertMyQuery}}?batch=true"></to>
                                    <log message="Inserted rows ${body}"></log>
                                </when>
                            </choice>
                         </pipeline>
                     </multicast>
                  </pipeline>
              </multicast>
            </route>
         </routeContext>
```

Is it possible to do that?
When i am trying to do that, my program is not getting executed successfully.
Is the unsuccessful execution is a result of mulitple multicast?
Can anybody help?
I got the reference from following link:
http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html

Comment: Not quit sure I follow, can you edit your question with some code to show what you want to achieve even if it is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use pipeline? It "is" pipeline by default.

Also all the log and transform and choice statements can be put outside of the multicast. And since you are generating your endpoints dynamically, put the values in a header and use recipientlist for dynamic endpoints. Multicast is for hard-coded endpoints. Here is an example:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:a" />
  <!-- use comma as a delimiter for String based values -->
  <recipientList delimiter=",">
    <header>myHeader</header>
  </recipientList>
</route>
```

http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Comment: I have multiple processes running under inner multicast, thats why i used pipeline.